# Normal Map gives black render on half the surfaces

Tags: normal-map

White walls, added a Normal Map.

Here is the file with the Normal Map:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lM8D70NWvQbNrYpkS4LUn7HvoDohJmcu/view?usp=sharing

Tried:

- recalculate normals
- invert GREEN channel
- image is set as NON-COLOR
- the object is FLAT SHADING

These are chunks from the viewport in Cycles:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

This is in Eevee viewport:
[image]

And this is a render:
[image]

And this is a render with the RED channel inverted:
[image]

And this is the viewport in Cycles without NM:
[image]

And this is the face orientation:
[image]
I activated backface culling, so there's no way any of the faces shown are backflipped.

Aaaand... this is the shader:
[image]

Nothing fancy really- I really don't know where else to bang my head now.

I don't seem to be able to use Normal Maps in Blender, though I perfectly know how they work, and worked with them for many years, I always meet some kind of problem in Blender.
What is the secret?

Edit: under suggestion, tried to plug some vector nodes in the shader:
[image]

Comment: try giving it a texture coordinate node plugged into a mapping node set to UV and reset your UV maps

Comment: The UV were good, very simply unwrapped as they were, as this is a seamless texture. I added the nodes as you said, but it didn't work. Here is the setup, not sure it's correct: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RIG_QwyWz4vZ8r-gFVDImY-0-0ur1DrJ/view?usp=sharing  
Reset UV gave me a terrible, terrible setup.

Comment: The fact that Eevee does some type of automatic interpretation is kind of neat.

Answer (score 1):

You need a *Normal Map* Node between the *Image Texture* and *Principled Shader*.

[image]

Now beware that this *Strength* parameter is in units at the scene scale, so most likely by default this is going to try to make it appear such that the highest point is jutted out by an entire meter.  It has to do this without affecting the geometry so it is likely to also give you some visual artifacts (such as pure black cracks) right out of the box.

I usually set it to .3 or lower before I even enter rendered view, and then adjust by eye.

Comment: Thank you! That saved me. Though for some reason a value of about 0.05-.0.1 is right for me, as this is a **very** subtle effect of wall plaster.